Filter out the latest message of user whether it is in sender or reciver by item id
i tired group by with item id by using max with id but not able to filter out the single row only for each item id in table with latest message whether user login as sender or receiver. below is my table for chats between sender and receiver for particular item id
I want the solution like each item id last/latest message between sender and receiver and need single row only to to show chat list.
I tried this query but its returning only single row but i want all rows where user have new message.
SELECT id,
   `sender`,
   `receiver`,
   `message`, 
   `created_at`
FROM chats
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) 
             FROM chats
             WHERE `sender` = 2 OR `receiver` = 2
             GROUP BY IF (`sender` = 2, `sender`, `receiver`))
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC;

Expected Result =>


A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

Is the  tag really relevant here?

Which MySQL version are you using?

@jarlh MySQL version i am using is 8.0

With MySQL 8, a window function query would be more performant (than a join).
